# Can't retrieve entity config: core/store_group

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have transfer the magento site to  another server. Fist of all I have installed fresh magento and upload the all files and folder. I have updated database as well. Previously the error was different. But I have searched in the web and fount some solution (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/71051/) and now the error coming like this.
I have already uploaded lib/Varien/SimpleXML folder of magento 17.

```
Can't retrieve entity config: core/store_group
```

**Trace:**

```
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(140): Mage::throwException('Can't retrieve ...')
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(228): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName('core/store_grou...')
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(211): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->getTable('store_group')
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Collection/Abstract.php(83): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->getMainTable()
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Collection/Abstract.php(69): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract->_initSelect()
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(790): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Store_Group))
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(832): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_mysql4/sto...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Store_Group))
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/Mage.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/store_grou...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Store_Group))
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(200): Mage::getResourceModel('core/store_grou...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Store_Group))
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(373): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(244): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/Mage.php(427): Mage_Core_Model_App->init('', 'store', Array)
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/app/Mage.php(446): Mage::app('', 'store', Array)
/homepages/20/d317798792/htdocs/imedicia/site/index.php(52): Mage::run()
{main}
```

Comment: This would be better suited for http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewchild/42329/

Comment: Check if core_store_group table exists. if yes flush cache and then check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue when deploying Magento 1.9.3.10 to a store that was previously running 1.9.3.9.

In the process, I was also replacing the Inchoo PHP7 compatibility module with the "official" Magento-core-team provided patch.

When I deployed the code update, I began getting an exception message on every page. The exception was `Can't retrieve entity config: core/store_group` (same as the OP).

In my case, the solution was to manually delete all redis keys for that store using `redis-cli`. Trying to clear the cache with Magento's CLI tool did NOT work (probably the cache was too corrupted).

After clearing redis, the store came back online and worked properly, so if you encounter this error, I recommend clearing your cache without relying on Magento tools.

If you use filesystem cache, that means `rm -rf {magento_root}/var/cache`.

For redis, if you have only one store using that redis DB, it means `redis flushall`

If you have multiple stores using the same redis DB, you need something like:

`redis-cli -h '{redis_hostname}' KEYS '{redis_prefix}*' | xargs redis-cli -h '{redis_hostname}' del`

* Tip: Get those values from `/app/etc/local.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Check core_store_group table, and also for files.
May be files are missing.
Flush cache.

Answer (score 0):

- This is definitely an issue with the **app/etc/local.xml and app/etc/config.xml**
- Try replacing these files with some other running version of same app
- This has done the trick for me every time I setup my new machine
- I hope this would be helpful for others